# jQuery / ajax: I want to set an initial value for a combo box, then have a dropdown list of other values. How can I do that?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, combobox, flexbox

I want to have a combo box and set an initial value for it. But I still want the user to be able to click to see a dropdown list of options that are different from the initial value.

An example of what I have in mind is the public transportation direction of [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=&daddr=Harvard%20Square,%20Cambridge,%20MA%2002138&hl=en&geocode=&mra=ls&dirflg=r&ttype=dep&date=04/01/11&time=12:55am&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&sll=42.328403,-71.107302&sspn=0.011945,0.01929&ie=UTF8&start=0&z=16). You can see that in the rightmost combo box, the initial value is set at the current time. But the user can still click on the arrow and see a dropdown list of values that are different from the initial value.

I've looked at [FlexBox](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox) but whenever I set an initial value, only that initial value is present in the dropdown list. You can see that in this [demo #7](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos.aspx#demo7).

Is there any way to configure FlexBox to do what I need? Or is there another combo box I can use? What does Google use for their Google Maps combo box?

Thanks.

Comment: try with `select box` and set default value as `selected` option.. isn't a good and easy idea??

Comment: Are you talking about HTML Select? As stated in the question, I need a combo box. That is because I need to give the user the option to just type in free text in addition to selecting from a drop down list.

Comment: what means by combo box?? read [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/blnav7.htm)

Comment: @diEcho -- by combo box, I mean a single input box where the user can either type in text, or select from a drop down list. For example please see the FlexBox or the Google Maps links I included in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I use [msdropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) and although i never used [giva labs](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm) it seems like a good option.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for an autocompleter? This flavor of the jQuery autocompleter seems to be what you're searching for.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox does not support this natively, although modification is pretty easy.

The issue is that the initialValue setting also overrides the display.

The following instructions are for version 0.9.6.1, non-min version of flexBox:

```
Line 63:
Add:
        if (o.initialValueNoDisplay != '') $hdn.val(o.initialValueNoDisplay);
After: 
        .appendTo($div);


Line 832 (833):
Add:
        initialValueNoDisplay: '',
After:
        initialValue: '',
```

Just set the value as the initialValueNoDisplay rather than the initialValue.  I tested with MVC3/Razor, seems to work fine.